# Incremental web publishing and preview changes with Visual Studio 2012 to local file system or FTP

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, publishing

I'm trying to set up a publishing workflow for an ASP.NET site I'm working on. It will be located in a shared/network folder and I would like to publish from Visual Studio 2012.

I have seen that VS 2012 has some improvements when publishing a site, like previewing changes and incremental deployment but all the tutorials I have seen so far are showing Windows Azure, for example:

http://www.techbubbles.com/aspnet/web-publishing-features-in-visual-studio-2012/

Does VS 2012 support change previews and incremental publishing to local file system or FTP or only just for Azure ?

If not, are there any alternatives ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also get these features using a web deploy publishing profile pointed at a IIS instance on your network.  Here's the [relevant MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337.aspx).